# Acceder a un objeto dentro del state mediante parametro

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Tengo un par de combobox que lleno con el state el objeto se ve así:

```
[
productos: [
    { id: "1", value: "Tennis", estado: false },
    { id: "2", value: "Camisa", estado: false },
    { id: "3", value: "Fajas", estado: false }
  ],
producto: { id: "", value: "", estado: false }
]
```

Donde el el valor de la opción sería el id y la descripción sería el value. Al seleccionar una opción, el objeto producto se actualiza con la opción seleccionada y habilita un checkbox que al darle click debería cambiar el estado del objeto producto y posteriormente buscar en el objeto productos el producto seleccionado y cambiar el estado ahi también. Tengo 3 combo con la misma estructura, por lo que quiero hacer una función generica para darle el valor al objeto producto u otro objeto con esta estructura y posteriormente otra para actualizar el estado. La primera función luce algo así:

```
handleDropdown(event) {
const objetoSeleccionado = event.target.value;
if (!(objetoSeleccionado === null || objetoSeleccionado === undefined)) {
  const objeto = this.state.[event.target.name].find(
    objeto => objeto.id === objetoSeleccionado
  );
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: objeto
  });
  enableInputs();
 }
}
```

Entonces en la línea que hace el `this.state.[event.target.name].find` me arroja el error de unexpected token. Entonces, hay algúna manera de hacer esto o tengo que crear una función para cada combo?

Actualización:
Según la respuesta de Emeeus, logré lo que deseaba. Lo que quería hacer era algo así:

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productos: [
        { id: "1", value: "Tennis", estado: false },
        { id: "2", value: "Camisa", estado: false },
        { id: "3", value: "Fajas", estado: false }
      ],
      producto: { id: "", value: "", estado: false }
    };

    this.handleDropdown = this.handleDropdown.bind(this);
    this.handleDropDownState = this.handleDropDownState.bind(this);
  }

  handleDropdown(event) {
    const objetoSeleccionado = event.target.value;

    if (!(objetoSeleccionado === null || objetoSeleccionado === undefined)) {
      const objeto = this.state[event.target.name].find(
        objeto => objeto.id === objetoSeleccionado
      );
      //La key producto está hardcodeada por mi
      this.setState(
        {
          producto: objeto
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state); //<-- este callback es solo para mostrar state
        }
      );
    }
  }

  handleDropDownState(event) {
    if (!(event.target.name === null || event.target.name === undefined)) {
      let producto = this.state.producto;
      producto.estado = event.target.checked;
      this.setState({ [event.target.name]: producto });

      this.setState({
        [this.state.productos.map(
          productoFinal => productoFinal.id === producto.id
        )]: [producto]
      });
      console.log(this.state);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select name="productos" onChange={e => this.handleDropdown(e)}>
          {this.state.productos.map((p, i) => {
            return (
              <option key={i} value={p.id}>
                {p.value}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="estadoProducto">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id="producto"
            name="producto"
            value={this.state.producto.estado}
            onChange={this.handleDropDownState}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas cosas que hay que suponer, pero lo que encuentro es, error de sintáxis en `this.state.[event.target.name]` y un tema en `.setState`, este no debería actualizar la clave que viene de `[event.target.name]`, porque este apunta al mismo elemento que estamos iterando (`productos` en mi suposición) y dejaría de ser un array (entre otras cosas), en el ejemplo hardcodeo el name porque no se si vendrá de otro lado:

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     productos: [
            { id: "1", value: "Tennis", estado: false },
            { id: "2", value: "Camisa", estado: false },
            { id: "3", value: "Fajas", estado: false }
          ],
     producto: { id: "", value: "", estado: false }      
    }
  }
  
  handleDropdown(event){
        const objetoSeleccionado = event.target.value;
        
      if (!(objetoSeleccionado === null || objetoSeleccionado === undefined)) {
        const objeto = this.state[event.target.name].find(
          objeto => objeto.id === objetoSeleccionado
        );
        //La key producto está hardcodeada por mi
        this.setState({
          ['producto']: objeto
        }, ()=>{
        console.log(this.state);//<-- este callback es solo para mostrar state
        });
     }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <select name="productos" onChange={(e)=>this.handleDropdown(e)}>
      {this.state.productos.map((p,i)=>{
      return <option key={i} value={p.id}>{p.value}</option>
      })}
      </select>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: consulta, en la línea que pones: "La key producto está hardcodeada por mi", ahi sigue el setState, yo estoy haciendo un
this.setState(
          {
            [this.state[elementName + "s"].map(
              productoFinal => productoFinal.id === objeto.id
            )]: [objeto]
          },
          () => {
            console.log(this.state[event.target.name]);
          }
        );
Pero, me arroja el error: The specified value "[object Object]" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: Me parece que no son necesarias las [ ] en [this.state[elementName + "s"] porque en teoría ya es un array, quiza eso se arrasta y luego arroja ese error.